# d_ply and dist() together

Tags: r, distance, plyr, correlation

I'm having trouble with a R code that I wrote. Particularly it looks like this:

```
n<- nrow(aa)
for (i in 1:n)
{
A<- aa[i,]
d_ply(A, 1, function(row){  
cu<- dist(A)
    write.table(cu, file = paste(row$header, "txt", sep     = "."), sep = "\t")
}, .progress='text', .print = TRUE)
}
```

I would like to obtain a single file from each row of aa matrix (the file name should be the header of the row), containing the distance matrix of that row, but seems very hard. If I try the code I get this error:

```
cannot coerce class '"dist"' into a data.frame
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you doing `d_ply` at all if you're applying it to only one row?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I need to apply to all rows!

Comment: But you're *already* applying it to all rows using your for loop. Within that for loop, `A` is just a single row.

Comment: Also, is `aa` a data frame or a matrix? It makes a big difference. (And where does `row$header` come from?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson It's a data frame (I use structure( , class = "data.frame") before of the code that you see above.

Comment: What is `row$header`? Can you do `dput(aa)` and edit in the result?

Comment: @DavidRobinson the 'row$header' takes the first column of each row for the outputfile name. (header is properly the word that I've in the aa header)

Comment: @DavidRobinson doing dput(head(aa)) I get a too long output. Anyway it starts with: structure(list(pluto = 1:6, q = c(1, 0.065076494, 1, 0.023431396, 
1, 1), q.1 = c(0.610399189, 0.038944176, 0.539411577, 1, 0.951827992, 
1) and it ends with this:   1)), .Names = c("pluto", "q", "q.1", "q.2", "q.3", "q.4", 
"q.5", "q.6", "q.7", "q.8", "q.9", "q.10", "q.11", "q.12", "q.13", 
"q.14", "q.15", "q.16", "q.17", "q.18", "q.19", "q.20", "q.21", 
"q.22", [... ] "q.92", "q.93", 
"q.94", "q.95", "q.96", "q.97", "q.98", "q.99"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please edit the entire output of `dput(head(aa))` into your question (click the `edit` link under your question)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23649/discussion-between-gabelins-and-david-robinson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, assuming `aa` is a data frame, then `A` is just a single row. You don't need to use the for loop if you're already using `d_ply`, which is designed to apply something to every row of a data frame.

The second issue is that `dist` returns a `dist` object, which has to be turned into a matrix before it can be written. The following code will do that:

Third, you need to convert the `row` from a one-row data frame to a vector before using `dist`.

This leads to the following code:

```
d_ply(aa, 1, function(row){  
    cu<- dist(as.numeric(row[-1]))
    write.table(as.matrix(cu), file = paste(row$header, "txt", sep = "."), sep = "\t")
}, .progress='text', .print = TRUE)
```

Comment: But I think you want `a_ply`, not `d_ply`; currently you'll be splitting the data frame based on the first column.

Comment: @hadley: Based on comments and chat, it looks like Gabelin's first column is called `header` and that it consists of `1:NROW(aa)`, such that they end up doing the same thing.

Comment: @DavidRobinson In that case, don't you want `as.numeric(row[-1])` ?

Comment: @hadley: Yes, presumably the OP does! I've set it as such in my answer, though Gabelin sounded satisfied in chat (and possibly didn't notice the extra column/row in the matrix)

Comment: @DavidRobinson  didn't have any extra colum/row :)